# VDSL2 Modem in bridged mode using IPV6 in LAN

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, ipv6

I have a VDSL2 IPv6 modem, it is bridged by default so usually sharing files between computers in LAN has happened with the same speed as my connection, which is 100/30 mbits. So basically all the transfers have happened at the rate of 30mbits which is my upload speed.

But suddenly I noticed that all mapped network drives transfers happen through IPv6 and it is all fast, +100mbits all the time in LAN.

Is it possible that even though the modem is in bridged mode and there is no specific "LAN" ip for machines, it somehow detects transfers in LAN and assigns them or routes them through IPv6 making it all local?

I couldnt explain this well enough since my I lack terminology and knowledge but yeah, before all transfers were rather slow between the computers in my local area network but now they are fast as heck and when I looked it all goes through IPv6 protocol.

Answer (score 0):

Any *DSL modem's WAN connection speed should have no effect on LAN-to-LAN speeds. Your LAN technology is what affects LAN speeds. So if you have a gigabit Ethernet switch connecting your LAN clients' gigabit Ethernet cards, you should have gigabit speeds on your LAN.

The IPv6 protocol has slightly larger headers than IPv4, so technically IPv6 should be slightly (around 1%) slower than IPv4, all else being equal.

None of the factors you've suggested so far are adequate explanations of the recent speed up you saw. Nor are they adequate explanations of the previous slowness you saw.

Answer (score 0):

This could have happened if your IPv4 traffic were somehow being routed via your "external" IPv4 address, being sent out the modem to the ISP and then right back in a U-turn. I can't really imagine how you would have gotten your local network into such a state that this would happen, though it's certainly possible that you did.

IPv6 doesn't really have a concept of "external" or an address translation boundary (at least, not one anyone takes seriously) and all of your IPv6 addresses are globally scoped. Thus your machines can now talk directly to each other on the LAN at its full speed. (This doesn't necessarily mean that "outside" machines can talk to you, provided you have a firewall!)

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are running IPv4 over PPP over Ethernet, which will force all IPv4 traffic via the router which is at the other end of the VDSL line. However your computers are using IPv6 directly over Ethernet and not using the modem (possibly using an Ethernet switch is the same box).